# Android development issues using eclipse mars

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I'm having an issue starting my android development as I've tried multiple solutions off this site for getting past eclipse not building blank activities and its not letting me begin my development and I have also tried updating and downloading the SDK but all my attempts have all deemed unsuccessful, could this be because I'm using eclipse mars.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to start using intelliJ IDEA. Just becouse you can do almost everything inside that one program and it seems to be faster than android studio for me.

Here is the download link: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Is there anyway to get around it using eclipse Mars Cause I have to for my coursework?

Comment: well, whatever you are doing in eclipse you can also do in intellIJ. But if your teachers insist on using eclipse then unfortunately I cant help cause I'm using intelliJ and android studio.